# I have an error in my XML file : attribute android:startOffSet not found and I don't get why

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, animation, xamarin.android

```
I use this XML file for a custom animation (CardView animation) using fragments.

I reviewed this File and could not find the problem.
```

‘’’’
>

```
  <objectAnimator
android:valueFrom="1.0"
android:valueTo="0.0"
android:propertyName="alpha"
android:duration="0"/>
 
<!--Rotate-->
  <objectAnimator
  android:valueFrom="180"
  android:valueTo="0"
  android:propertyName="rotationY"
  android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
  android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full"/>

<!--Half-way through the rotation set the alpha to 1-->
  <objectAnimator
android:valueFrom="0.0"
android:valueTo="1.0"
android:propertyName="alpha"
android:startOffSet="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
android:duration="1"/>
</set> ‘’’’
```

this is my xml file that should flip a fragment this is a part of a custom
animation, I am supposed to link this xml
in the main activity to make the card view
flip

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should at least provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

From android document [ValueAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html), we will find that method [setCurrentFraction()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#setCurrentFraction(float))

> Sets the position of the animation to the specified fraction.

So if we want to set the animation to an offset of 30% could be achieved with

```
 animator.setCurrentFraction(0.3f);
```

In xamarin android, you can  check document [android.animation.objectanimator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.animation.objectanimator?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13).

And the alternative method is [ValueAnimator.SetCurrentFraction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.animation.valueanimator.setcurrentfraction?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13#android-animation-valueanimator-setcurrentfraction(system-single)).